# Total count of values at each pixel in a raster stack/ 3d array

Tags: arcpy, raster, numpy, nodata

If you have an array with x, y and z dimensions, how can I create an array of x, y dimensions that holds a count of how many z values at each location (x,y) are noData?

I would prefer to use numpy and python for this task, but could also use arcpy (I am working with raster data) or R.

Comment: Was that code helpful for you?

Comment: @JamesSLC, , thank you both of your answers look very helpful.  I will do some testing over the next few days and respond as to which one was preferable for my work.  I would prefer to use solutions without the use of arcpy, as I don't have a license on my home computer, but your solution will work in the office!

Comment: Is the array already a `numpy.ndarray` or do you first need to read it from disk? How is your data structured?

Comment: Accepting the answer is not the only way to show appreciation for someone's time ;-) see site help center [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Kersten I the raster stack is already a numpy.ndarray.  I am also working on incorporating cloud and data quality masked, so may use the masked array format

Comment: @RyanM you could just as easily create bool arrays from the cloud and data quality layers and combine them with your raster stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you allready read your raster data into a numpy array called `raster_stack` and stacked all rasters along the z-axis.

```
import numpy as np

no_data = -32768
np.sum(raster_stack == no_data, axis=0)
```

This will result in a 2-dimensional array containing the count of `no_data` values for each x,y location. It will also be as fast as you can get with Python since all the looping is handled by `numpy` in fast C functions, instead of slow Python loops.

How does it work:

- `raster_stack == no_data` creates a `bool` array with the same dimensions as your `raster_stack` which contains `True` for all `no_data` observations.
- In numpy you can treat True/False like 1/0, meaning that `True + True` will equal `2`.
- `np.sum` sums up all True observations along the z-axis (`axis=0`) and returns the result as a flattened 2D-array.

---

To support my performance claim, let's compare this with the numpy method in @JamesSLC answer.

```
# create a test dataset, where the first and last 2 rasters contain no_data values
raster_stack = np.arange(200000).reshape(20, 100, 100)
raster_stack[raster_stack < 20000] = -32768
raster_stack[raster_stack > 180000] = -32768

# sum of no_data values without loops
def no_data(array, no_data):
    return np.sum(array == no_data, axis=0)

# sum of no_data values with masked_array and loops
def masked_no_data(array, no_data):
    out_raster_data = np.zeros((array.shape[1], array.shape[2]), np.int) 
    bands = range(array.shape[0])
    bands_list = []
    for i in bands:
        temp_array = np.array(raster_stack[i,:,:])
        masked_array = np.ma.masked_values(temp_array, no_data)
        bands_list.append(masked_array.mask)
    for i in xrange(0, len(bands)):
        out_raster_data += bands_list[i]
    return out_raster_data
```

.

```
# compare that both functions produce the same result
np.array_equal(no_data(raster_stack, -32768), masked_no_data(raster_stack, -32768))
>>True
```

.

```
%timeit no_data(raster_stack, -32768)
>>1000 loops, best of 3: 324 µs per loop
```

.

```
%timeit masked_no_data(raster_stack, -32768)
>>1000 loops, best of 3: 998 µs per loop
```

Using numpys internal functions without the masked array is roughly 3 times faster. It should be noted however that the vast majority of executing the real task will be spent reading the data into numpy arrays in the first place.

Comment: How would this compare/is it faster than the numpy native functions method I proposed above?

Comment: @JamesSLC see my edit. The proposed function is shorter and faster. I originally wanted to post this as a comment on your answer but onfortunately it was too long for that. Just my 2 cents on how to improve the numpy part of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** - Added additional method to compare with.

Using a mixture of `arcpy` and `numpy` the methods below should do the trick:

```
import arcpy, numpy

##Get Rasters bands as well as raster height, width, and no data value
in_path = r'' #enter the fullpath to your raster stack here
arcpy.env.workspace = in_path
bands = arcpy.ListRasters()
in_ras = arcpy.Raster(in_path)
raster_rows = in_ras.width
raster_columns = in_ras.height
no_data = in_ras.noDataValue # this property can be tricky so you may need to set the value manually

#create an empty numpy array of zeros the same size as input raster to store the results
out_raster_data = numpy.zeros((raster_columns, raster_rows), numpy.int)
```

From here I will present two different ways you can go.

The first method (shown below) relies on **native numpy functions**. It uses native methods from numpy to mask data based on the provided no data value. This method is **much faster**:

```
bands_list = []
for i in bands:
    temp_array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(i).astype(numpy.float32)
    masked_array = numpy.ma.masked_values(temp_array, no_data)
    bands_list.append(masked_array.mask) #use the mask from masked_array that is an array of True/False values depending on if the value in the array was no_data or not

for i in xrange(0, len(bands)):
    out_raster_data += bands_list[i] #perform addition on the Boolean mask arrays (1 for False (no_data), 0 for True (data))
```

The second method is a **looping method** which loops over the pixels/array elements individually. This method is **much slower**.

```
#Create a list that houses each raster array
bands_list = []
for i in bands:
    bands_list.append(arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(i).astype(numpy.float32))

#loop over all columns, rows, then bands
#loop over bands last to get a value from each band and increase the output pixel value if it is equal to no_data
for y in xrange(0, raster_columns):
    for x in xrange(0, raster_rows):
        out_pixel_data = 0
        for j in range(0,len(bands)):
            sample_value = bands_list[j][y,x]
            if sample_value == no_data:
                out_pixel_data += 1
        out_raster_data[y,x] = out_pixel_data
```

To save the output in raster format for both methods, you can finish with this:

```
#convert numpy array to raster and save the results
result_raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(out_raster_data)
result_raster.save(r'') #enter output raster path here
```

If you are working with a spatial reference you will need to project the resulting raster either when converting to raster or after the fact.